# Create a thumbnail and then convert to byte array

Tags: arrays, thumbnails, system.drawing

I'm having a heck of a time with creating thumbnails and then converting them into a byte array.  I've tried three methods, and all 3 times I get an error.

The first was using Bitmap.GetThumbnailImage, which I have used in the past and then saved directly into Response.OutputStream

The second was using System.Drawing.Graphics with DrawImage().  Still no go.

The third was just to create a new bitmap, pass in the old bitmap, and set the new size.  Same error.

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: encoder 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: encoder
>   Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: encoder]
>      System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +615244

Here is the code for my method.  Maybe someone will see what I'm doing wrong.  In case you aren't sure about GetThumbSize, it's simply a method that takes in the image size and the maximum thumb size and then computes an actual size to preserve the aspect ratio.

```
public static System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort thumbnailCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

    public static bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image"></param>
    /// <param name="size"></param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method will throw a AccessViolationException when the machine OS running the server code is windows 7.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] CreateThumbnail(byte[] imageData, Size size)
    {
        using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            inStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);

            using (System.Drawing.Image image = Bitmap.FromStream(inStream))
            {
                Size thumbSize = GetThumbSize(new Size(image.Width, image.Height), size);

                //do not make image bigger
                if (thumbSize.Equals(image.Size) || (image.Width < size.Width || image.Height < size.Height))
                {
                    //if no shrinking is ocurring, return the original bytes
                    return imageData;
                }
                else
                {
                    using (System.Drawing.Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbSize.Width, thumbSize.Height, thumbnailCallback, IntPtr.Zero))
                    {

                        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            thumb.Save(outStream, thumb.RawFormat);

                            return outStream.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This line is throwing the error:

```
thumb.Save(outStream, thumb.RawFormat);
```

Any ideas?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This issue on Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=98452

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem may be the original image's encoding. IIRC, Save(stream, format) results in a call to Save(stream, encoder, params), with the encoder being taken from the format; which in your case is the original format of the image.

According to the Community Content for the [Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx), some formats will not translate well into an appropriate encoder.

I would suggest you specify the encoder yourself, using some standard format like PNG.

Try:

```
thumb.Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Png, null); // optionally add encoder parameters here, like quality or luminescence
```

Comment: Your suggestion lead me to try something.  I had just written a method to convert the ImageFormat into a mimetype.  I ran the format of the original image through this and it returned "image/gif", which was as expected because the file extension is .gif.

Then I replaced the offending like with:

thumb.Save(outStream, image.RawFormat);

and it works.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is save it in a Raw format you can try the following, as in my case it works when the original image format is a supported one:

```
try
{
   thumb.Save(outStream, img.RawFormat);
}
catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
{
   thumb.Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```