# Rotate byte array Image and encode to Base64 string

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, rotation, base64

I am having a very difficult time trying to figure this one out:

I am working with a front-end which

1. Reads an image taken from a mobile device to a byte array
2. Converts the byte array to be stored as a Base64 string
3. Sends the Base64 string to a database

The back-end is only slated to store images as Base64 strings, as it later embeds the image as a Base64 string to an email for the user whose email application will only show Base64-embedded images. The problem is that the images are embedding 90 degrees counter-clockwise in the email, so I am trying to rotate the image 90 degrees before encoding the base64 string which is inserted into a Sql stored procedure (executed from the application). I feel like this code should simply do the trick:

```
HttpPostedFile img = imageUpload.PostedFile;
Stream stream = img.InputStream;
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
// Rotate Image Code (help):
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
var rotateImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);                  rotateImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, rotateImage.RawFormat);
bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
// End Rotate Image Code
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

But I am receiving an error when I try and run it:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: encoder at the line "bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();"

When I try and save it as a jpeg the image gets chopped off at the top, but no other formats work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the line:

```
rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, rotateImage.RawFormat);
```

Maybe you should specify the format. Try with:

```
rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Or even better, you can catch and force convertion only when there is an exception:

```
try
{
    rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, rotateImage.RawFormat);
}
catch (System.ArgumentNullException) 
{
    rotateImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

I think the issue is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269491/2986652)

Comment: When I do this it cuts the image at the top

Comment: Maybe one of these examples would help you to rotate before saving the image correctly: https://www.programmingnotes.org/7446/cs-how-to-resize-rotate-image-convert-image-to-byte-array-change-image-format-fix-image-orientation-using-cs/